# Edit nested dictionary duplicate values in same keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dicts with the same structure

```
[{"Program Name": "Bulldozer", "Level": 3}, {"Program Name": "Robot", "Level": 1}, {"Program Name": "Bulldozer", "Level": 4}]
```

What I want is duplicate keys of "Program Name" that have the same value (ex: "Bulldozer" appearing 2x) to be renamed as "Bulldozer (1)", "Bulldozer (2)" and so on.

Comment: Can you share your attempt?

Comment: Is your input correct? How a list can have key value pair?

Comment: Does the order matter?

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA It does not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Efficient way is to use `defaultdict` to count the `"Program Name"`, the time complexity
is `O(n)`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

l = [{"Program Name": "Bulldozer", "Level": 3}, {"Program Name": "Robot", "Level": 1},
     {"Program Name": "Bulldozer", "Level": 4}, {"Program Name": "Bulldozer", "Level": 4}, {"Program Name": "Robot", "Level": 1}]

tmp = defaultdict(int)
for i in l:
    i["Program Name"] = f'{i["Program Name"]} ({tmp[i["Program Name"]]})' if tmp[i["Program Name"]] else i["Program Name"]
    tmp[i["Program Name"].split()[0]] += 1

print(l)
```

Result:

```
[{'Program Name': 'Bulldozer', 'Level': 3}, {'Program Name': 'Robot', 'Level': 1}, {'Program Name': 'Bulldozer (1)', 'Level': 4}, {'Program Name': 'Bulldozer (2)', 'Level': 4}, {'Program Name': 'Robot (1)', 'Level': 1}]
```

Comment: Seems to seperate names with spaces like if i have a program name with "Bulldozer Rambo" it will start collectiong the Bulldozer name by its own and not the entire "Bulldozer Rambo" name. Fixed it by removing the split()[0]

Comment: @Crapy If so. You could use `tmp[" ".join(i["Program Name"].split()[:-1])] += 1` or regex to  split them.

Comment: @Crapy If you remove the `split`, the full name `"xxx (1)"` will be added in the `tmp` which is not what you want.You could use print(tmp) to see it.This will occur some unexpected behavior when there are three or more duplicate `"Program Name"`.

Comment: I tried your solution with the split()[:-1] But it seems to not work well for complicated names like Bulldozer Mega (Q7-4) for example

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
input = [{"Program Name": "Bulldozer", "Level": 3}, {"Program Name": "Robot", "Level": 1}, {"Program Name": "Bulldozer", "Level": 4}]

def update_input(input):

    existing_program_names = {}

    for i, d in enumerate(input):
        current_list_program_name = d['Program Name']

        try:
            existing_program_names[current_list_program_name] += 1
        except KeyError:
            # Program name not in storage yet add it
            existing_program_names.update({current_list_program_name: 0})

        if existing_program_names[current_list_program_name] > 0 :
            ID = existing_program_names[current_list_program_name]
            input[i]['Program Name'] = current_list_program_name + ' ({ID})'.format(ID=ID)
        else:
            pass
    return input

output = update_input(input)
```

yields:

```
[{'Program Name': 'Bulldozer', 'Level': 3}, {'Program Name': 'Robot', 'Level': 1}, {'Program Name': 'Bulldozer (1)', 'Level': 4}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this too:

```
data = [
    {"Program Name": "Bulldozer", "Level": 3},
    {"Program Name": "Robot", "Level": 1},
    {"Program Name": "Bulldozer", "Level": 4},
    {"Program Name": "Rozer", "Level": 3},
    {"Program Name": "Robot", "Level": 1},
    {"Program Name": "Rozer", "Level": 3},
    {"Program Name": "Bulldozer", "Level": 3},
    {"Program Name": "Robot", "Level": 1},
    {"Program Name": "Bulldozer", "Level": 4},
    {"Program Name": "Rozer", "Level": 3},
    {"Program Name": "Robot", "Level": 1},
    {"Program Name": "Rozer", "Level": 3}
]
```

`Approach: 01`

```
import pandas as pd


c = pd.DataFrame(data)
c['group_code'] = c.groupby(['Program Name']).cumcount() + 1
c['Program Name'] = ["{0} ({1})".format(x, y) for (x, y) in c[[
    'Program Name', 'group_code']].values]
output = c[['Program Name', 'Level']].to_dict(orient='records')
print(output)
```

`Approach: 02`

```
temp = {}
for item in data:
    temp.update(
        {
            item['Program Name']: temp[item['Program Name']] + 1 if temp.get(item['Program Name']) else 1
        }
    )
    item['Program Name'] = item['Program Name'] + ' (' + str(temp[item['Program Name']]) + ')'

print(data)
```

output:

```
[
    {"Program Name": "Bulldozer (1)", "Level": 3},
    {"Program Name": "Robot (1)", "Level": 1},
    {"Program Name": "Bulldozer (2)", "Level": 4},
    {"Program Name": "Rozer (1)", "Level": 3},
    {"Program Name": "Robot (2)", "Level": 1},
    {"Program Name": "Rozer (2)", "Level": 3},
    {"Program Name": "Bulldozer (3)", "Level": 3},
    {"Program Name": "Robot (3)", "Level": 1},
    {"Program Name": "Bulldozer (4)", "Level": 4},
    {"Program Name": "Rozer (3)", "Level": 3},
    {"Program Name": "Robot (4)", "Level": 1},
    {"Program Name": "Rozer (4)", "Level": 3}
]
```

I would recommend you to use `pandas(approach 01)` if you have huge amount of data.

Comment: Bulldozer is just an example the list has 10,000 dicts and a lot of different program names

Comment: Though the `approach 2` is very similar to @jizhihaoSAMA answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @jizhihaoSAMA I have managed to find a solution to my problem with a small edit

```
machines = [{"Program Name": "Bulldozer", "Level": 3}, {"Program Name": "Robot", "Level": 1}, {"Program Name": "Bulldozer", "Level": 4}]
        tmp = defaultdict(int)
        for i in machines:
            name = i["Program Name"].strip(f' ({tmp[i["Program Name"]]})')
            i["Program Name"] = f'{name} ({tmp[i["Program Name"]]})' if tmp[name] else i["Program Name"]
            tmp[name] += 1
```

This disables problems with spaces in the program name or any complexed names.